# Which timezone does Django use in DateField's auto_now_add?

Tags: python, django, django-models, timezone

How does Django write the date field when the field is marked with `auto_now_add` attribute?

Is it like `datetime.now().date()` or `timezone.now().date()`?

In other words, which timezone does it use to get the current date?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like it uses [`datetime.date.today()`](https://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.today), which would be the local date of the system:

[**db/models/fields/__init__.py**](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.7/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L1146):

```
class DateField(Field):
    ...
    def pre_save(self, model_instance, add):
        if self.auto_now or (self.auto_now_add and add):
            value = datetime.date.today()
            setattr(model_instance, self.attname, value)
            return value
```

If you wanted a different behavior you could remove `auto_now_add=True` then connect the model's [`pre_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.pre_save) signal  to a receiver that would set your field to the date of your choice.

Alternatively, you could override the model's [`save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.save) method and set the field there.

Answer (score 0):

Django by default uses the timezone mentioned in your settings.py TIME_ZONE attribute.

By default it is set to something like:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
```

More details on its usages could be found here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/timezones/